# Hashing password before update a user in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I create the user, hash his password and save on mongo. My problem begins when I try to update that user. For now, when I update the hash isn't generated, cause I really don't know how to do it.

The middleware to get the user that I'm talking about:

```
exports.userByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
  User.findOne(
    {
      _id: id
    },
    function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        req.user = user;
        next();
      }
    }
  );
};
```

The user controller, to update an user:

```
exports.update = async function(req, res, next) {

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, req.body, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(user);
    }
  });
};
```

The pre 'save' on User's model:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function(next) {

  var user = this;

  if (user.password) {

    var md5 = crypto.createHash("md5");
    user.password = md5.update(user.password).digest("hex");
    console.log("Password após o save (hasheando):" + user.password);
  }

  next();
});
```

I'm using passport authentication ('local'). Already tried `user.save()` on the controller update:

```
user.save();
res.json(user);
```

But, without success.

Comment: are you awaiting the `user.save()`?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but are you sure that the value was not updated? Did you check in the database, or only the value returned via `res.json()` in your controller? Also, is your pre('save') function being called at all?

Comment: Please don't use md5 for password hashing. It is [far too easy](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) to brute force. Try googling argon2 or just let [a module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-password) handle the hashing

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I will use another hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is may be because you are not storing the `new_password` in the mongo.

In `update controller` you have to do like this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, req.body, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  } else {
    user.password = req.body.new_password;
    user.save(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Error: ", err);
      } else {
        res.send("password updated successfully!");
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: this is the perfect solution

Comment: this might not be the good option giving that you are running two separated thing. The findByIdAndUpdate will save the raw password into your db. You will then run another save with the hashed password. Might be quite dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the password just hash it and update it in DB. it will be something like below.

```
 exports.update = async function(req, res, next) {
  let { body} = req;
  if(body['password']){
    var md5 = crypto.createHash("md5");
    body['password']= md5.update(body['password']).digest("hex");
  }
  let updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, body)
};
```